# Page Fault Exception Handlers and Updating Page Tables

Tags: kernel, virtual-memory, page-fault

In reading about how page faults and page hits are handled by the page fault exception handler, one thing wasn't clear to me. If a process is using a shared page and a page fault happens, when the page fault exception handler updates the page table entry in the page table for the process that caused the page fault, does it also update the page table entries in all of the other processes that share that same page? From my reading on the topic it seems like it only updates the page table entry in the page table for the faulting process but then how do the other processes know that that page has been paged in? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the issues you have to address in the design of your memory manager. One possible design is to have a shadow PTE for every page which can be shared. When a process faults on a shared page, the memory manager checks the shadow PTE. If the shadow PTE is not resident, it handles the page fault in the normal way, updating both the faulting processes PTE and the shadow PTE when the page is available. If the shadow PTE is resident then it simply copies the shadow PTE to the process PTE. This way process PTEs only get updated when the process actually touches the page. This is how I think Windows does it - my knowledge of Linux is limited, but since nearly every page in a Linux process can be shared at any time (due to fork) I expect that they have a different way of doing things to handle the sharing without having to have shadow PTEs for every single page in the system.

In this model, some cleverness is needed if you have asynchronous page fault handling, since you need to handle the case where another process faults on a page while it is being faulted in. You also need to handle the paging out case. In that case you would need to go through every process that has the page in its working set and remove it, which may require some IPI's and some book keeping.